How not to duplicate a complex expression in an if condition and the result expression in Excel
Frequently I want to check a complex condition and if valid, use the result as the result statement such as:
=IF(RC2+R1C>1.33,RC2+R1C,"")
Here, in a simple example, the RC2+R1C is repeated. However, it can get very complex.
A little more complex example:
=IF(ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP(RC1,INDIRECT("'"&R1C&"'!C5:C7",FALSE),3,FALSE)),VLOOKUP(RC1,INDIRECT("'"&R1C&"'!C5:C7",FALSE),3,FALSE),"")
Here the VLOOKUP(RC1,INDIRECT("'"&R1C&"'!C5:C7",FALSE),3,FALSE) is repeated.
Is this just the nature of Excel? It creates lines of duplicate code that are difficult to read and understand a year later. Does Excel optimize this repetition, or is it executed twice?
I have looked through various support/community sites, but it's hard to find an answer because it's hard to know how to search for this kind of issue.
